# shortened field name in django for mongodb usage

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models, django-nonrel, django-mongodb-engine

I'm using django-norel + mongodb + django-mongo-engine to build some application. for mongodb, a short enough field name is meaningful to save some space use bcz the the field name will completely exist in the record.

For django development, is there any open source project can automatically handle field-name shortening on the model level (probably extend the django model class to automatically convert field name to a shortened form before querying database)?